# Use ActiveSupport Around-Callbacks to execute code (tracing/logging) around when my services are invoked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, trace, activesupport

In my app/services directory, I have a bunch of services that each have an initialize method and a public `perform` method that takes no arguments.

A simple example service to show the structure might look like this:

```
module Users
  class CreateService

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def perform
    # code to create the user
  end
end
```

My goal is to add tracing to my application so that I can have traces for when each of my services in invoked, without needing to significantly modify the code of each of my services. In the end, I am hoping to make it so that when any of my services has its `perform()` method called, traces are automatically generated.

I believe this should be possible using ActiveSupport::Callbacks, similarly to how ActiveJob lets us define, say, around_perform callbacks for our jobs. I attempted to create a concern that I could include in my services which would instrument the desired behavior

```
module Traceable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks

  included do
    include ActiveSupport::Callbacks

    define_callbacks :perform

    set_callback :perform, :around, lambda { |r, block|
      puts "start the trace"
      result = block.call
      puts "end the trace"
    }
  end
end
```

However, after including this concern, the callback I'd like to define (uniform for all services) still isn't getting called. How can I make this work? Thank you!

References:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html
https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-around_perform (view the source code for the `around_perform` class method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way would be to make use of [prepended](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/09/23/prepend-class-methods-for-concerns.html).

It'll look like this:

```
module Traceable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  prepended do
    include ActiveSupport::Callbacks

    define_callbacks :trace

    set_callback :trace, :around do |_r, block|
      puts "start the trace"
      block.call
      puts "end the trace"
    end
  end

  def perform
    run_callbacks :trace do
      super
    end
  end
end

module Users
  class CreateService
    prepend Traceable

    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize(name)
      @name = name
    end

    def perform
      # code to create the user
      puts "perform"
    end
  end
end
```

The link has more details. The `prepend` in the service means that `Users::CreateService.perform` will first look for its definition in the `Traceable` module. That allows `Traceable` to wrap `perform` in the callback(s).

Since we're using `prepend` instead of `include` in the service, we need to call `define_callbacks` and `set_callback` inside of `ActiveSupport::Concern`'s `prepended` block.

If you `prepend` the `Traceable` module in your service, you don't really need `callbacks` or `concerns` at all. The `Traceable` module could just be this, and it would have the same outcome:

```
module Traceable
  def perform
    puts "before"
    super
    puts "after"
  end
end

module Users
  class CreateService
    prepend Traceable
    ...
  end
end
```